# some javascript functions isn't working in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm new to Cordova, and I'm trying to build an android app
I copied my files into www file and replaced its files with mine
and build apk but when running it on my phone the first two buttons only are working (Equal weight / Unequal weight) while the (add more/ reset/ result buttons ) are not, but when I'm trying to check my code as a web page it works perfectly, as you might see in the snippet

I also tried to keep the cordova.js file and the index.js with my app.js but it didn't work

I tried to add cordova.js and index.js (the files that created automatically when creating a project with Cordova) but it didn't work

```js
//declare the main buttons and divs
const btn1 = document.querySelector('.eqbtn'),
  btn2 = document.querySelector('.uneqbtn'),
  div1 = document.querySelector('.eqdiv'),
  div2 = document.querySelector('.wrap-sub')
div_2 = document.querySelector('.uneqdiv');

//add event listeners to the main buttons
btn1.addEventListener('click', equalFunc);
btn2.addEventListener('click', unequalFunc);

//switch between two keys
function equalFunc() {
  togFunc(div1, div_2, btn1, btn2);
  resetFunc('.eqdiv', div1);
}

function unequalFunc() {
  togFunc(div_2, div1, btn2, btn1);
  resetFunc('.wrap-sub', div2);
}

function togFunc(one, two, a, b) {
  a.classList.add('active');
  b.classList.remove('active');
  one.style.display = 'block';
  two.style.display = 'none';
}

//declare the equal addmore button
const btnplus = document.querySelector('.eqmore');
const unbtnplus = document.querySelector('.un-eqmore');

//fire when addmore button get fired
btnplus.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (checkIn('.eqdiv') === false) {
    errIn();
  } else {
    creatIn(div1);
  }
});

//fire when uneqaddmore get clicked
unbtnplus.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (checkIn('.wrap-sub') === false) {
    errIn();
  } else {
    creatIn(div2);
  }
})
//check the value of the inputs
function checkIn(nav) {
  let bool;
  document.querySelectorAll(`${nav} input`).forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.value === '' || elem.value < 0) {
      elem.style.borderColor = '#f86868';
      bool = false;
    } else {
      elem.style.borderColor = '#D1D1D1';
    }
  });
  return bool;
}


//create the input and assign it's value
function creatIn(dnav) {
  if (dnav === div1) {
    const dive = document.createElement('div');
    dive.innerHTML = `<input type ='number'/>`;
    dnav.insertBefore(dive, btnplus);
  } else {
    const sp1 = document.createElement('div'),
      sp2 = document.createElement('div');
    sp1.innerHTML = `<input type ='number'>`;
    sp2.innerHTML = `<input type ='number'>`;
    document.querySelector('.div2-1').appendChild(sp2);
    document.querySelector('.div2-2').appendChild(sp1);
  }

}

//fire an error if the user insert wrong value
function errIn() {
  const errdiv = document.createElement('div');
  errdiv.innerHTML = `Please fill inputs with positive values`;
  errdiv.classList.add('errdiv');
  document.querySelector('.wrap').insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', errdiv);
  setTimeout(() => errdiv.remove(), 1800);
}

//fire when the reset button get clicked
function resetFunc(x, y) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`${x} input`).forEach(reset => {
    reset.remove();
  });
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = '';
  creatIn(y);
}

//reset all the inputs
document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', () => resetFunc('.eqdiv', div1));
document.querySelector('.un-reset').addEventListener('click', () => resetFunc('.wrap-sub', div2));

//fire when result button get fired
document.querySelector('.result').addEventListener('click', resFunc);
document.querySelector('.un-result').addEventListener('click', unresFunc);

//declare result function when result button get clicked
function resFunc() {
  if (checkIn('.eqdiv') === false) {
    errIn();
  } else {
    let arr = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('.eqdiv input').forEach(res => arr.push(Number(res.value)));
    const num = arr.length;
    const newarr = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    const mean = newarr / num;
    const resarr = [];
    arr.forEach(re => resarr.push((re - mean) * (re - mean)));
    const newresarr = resarr.reduce((c, v) => c + v);
    const norDev = Math.sqrt(newresarr / (num - 1));
    const dev = norDev / Math.sqrt(num);
    let mpv;
    if (!isNaN(dev)) {
      mpv = `${mean.toFixed(3)} ± ${dev.toFixed(3)}`;
    } else {
      mpv = `${mean.toFixed(3)}`;
    }
    displayResult(mpv);
  }
}

function unresFunc() {
  if (checkIn('.wrap-sub') === false) {
    errIn();
  } else {
    let allweight = [],
      allValues = [],
      subMeanArray = [],
      sub = [],
      semiFinal = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('.div2-2 input').forEach(w => allweight.push(Number(w.value)));
    const sumWeight = allweight.reduce((n, m) => n + m);
    document.querySelectorAll('.div2-1 input').forEach(s => allValues.push(Number(s.value)));
    for (i = 0; i < allweight.length; i++) {
      subMeanArray.push(allweight[i] * allValues[i]);
    }
    const sumMean = subMeanArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    const mean = sumMean / sumWeight;
    allValues.forEach(s => sub.push(s - mean));
    for (i = 0; i < allweight.length; i++) {
      semiFinal.push(allweight[i] * sub[i] * sub[i]);
    }
    const alFinal = semiFinal.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    const nDev = Math.sqrt(alFinal / allweight.length);
    const Dev = nDev / Math.sqrt(sumWeight);
    let mpv;
    if (isNaN(Dev)) {
      mpv = ` : No choice but the only value you gave which is ${allValues[0].toFixed(3)}`;
    } else {
      mpv = `${mean.toFixed(3)} ± ${Dev.toFixed(3)}`;
    }
    displayResult(mpv);
  }

}

function displayResult(wow) {
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = `The Result is ${wow}`;
}
```

```css
.wrap>div {
  display: none;
}


/* .uneqdiv{
   display: none;
} */

.container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: max-content;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrap {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.wrap-sub {
  display: flex;
}

.div2-1 {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  transition: border .3s;
}

.active,
.active:focus {
  border-color: #46d84d;
}

button.reset:hover,
button.un-reset:hover {
  border-color: #f86868;
}

button.eqmore:hover,
button.un-eqmore:hover {
  border-color: #46d84d;
}

.errdiv {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #df4f4f;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#output {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.tes {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container>h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  button {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 20rem;
  }
  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .eqdiv {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .eqdiv input {
    max-width: 20rem;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .eqdiv button {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .uneqdiv {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrap-sub input {
    max-width: 25rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .uneqdiv .wrap-sub {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .wrap-sub h6 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
  .tes button {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>survey</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="jui">Please select the wanted method</h2>
    <button class="eqbtn">equal weight</button>
    <button class="uneqbtn">unequal weight</button>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="eqdiv">
        <h4>Enter the equal values</h4>
        <div>
          <input type="number" class="init">
        </div>
        <button class="eqmore">add more +</button>
        <button class="reset">reset</button>
        <button class="result button-primary">result</button>
      </div>
      <div class="uneqdiv">
        <h4>Enter the unequal values</h4>
        <div class="wrap-sub">
          <div class="div2-1">
            <h6>The Measurements</h6>
            <input type="number" class="un-init">
          </div>
          <div class="div2-2">
            <h6>The Weights</h6>
            <input type="number" class="un-weight">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tes">
          <button class="un-eqmore">add more +</button>
          <button class="un-reset">reset</button>
          <button class="un-result button-primary">result</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using arrow functions and template literal sting in js those are from ES6 which may not be supported in android webview (depends on your version). You can transpile/compile your js using [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: my god, this could be really it.
thank you I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: I give it a try but still not working I guess the issue is the ${x} variable + input thing I compiled but still not working I guess it didn't get it or something
before compile, if you have any kind of idea I will be thankful for it
function resetFunc(x, y) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`${x} input`).forEach(reset => {
    reset.remove();
  });
 bla bla
}
after 
function resetFunc(x, y) {
  document.querySelectorAll("".concat(x, " input")).forEach(function(reset) {
    reset.remove();
  });
  bla bla bla
}

Comment: let, const keywords

Comment: @Eric when I compiled the code back to es5 the let/const keywords replaced by var but it didn't work when I'm removing stuff like " document.querySelectorAll(${x} input) " it just works and I don't think there is anything wrong with the way I wrote it because I'm gonna use the function in more than one place even the browser get it, so I'm completely lost

Comment: copy paste your whole JS to https://babeljs.io/ and it will give browser compatible js and use that into your source.

Comment: querySelectorAll does not work on Android webview

Comment: @ArpitVasani I did but I didn't work like it didn't make any difference

Comment: @Eric so is there any other syntax to use to make this example work

Comment: @ArpitVasani you're going to hate that answer but consider using jQuery for DOM manipulation on webview

Comment: yup you guessed my friend :'D 
thanks for your help any way I'll try a couple of times hoping to find a solution in js